# change pandas 0.13.0 "print dataframe" to print dataframe like in earlier versions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In the new version 0.13.0 of pandas, a dataframe df is printed in one long list of numbers using

```
df
```

or

```
print df
```

instead of an overview, like before, which is now only possible using

```
df.info()
```

Is it possible to change the default 'df' or 'print df' command to show :

```
In [12]: df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 4319 entries, 2010-02-18 00:00:00 to 2010-03-13 23:15:00
Data columns (total 2 columns):
QInt    4319  non-null values
QHea    4319  non-null values
dtypes: float32(2)
```

again instead of:

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
                                  QInt         QHea
2010-02-18 00:00:00         169.666672     0.000000
2010-02-18 00:15:00         152.000000    -0.000000
2010-02-18 00:15:00         152.000000    -0.000000
2010-02-18 00:30:00         155.000000    -0.000000
2010-02-18 00:30:04         155.063950    -0.000000
2010-02-18 00:30:04         155.063950 -1136.823364
2010-02-18 00:45:00         169.666672  4587.430176
2010-02-18 01:00:00         137.333328  4532.890137
2010-02-18 01:00:00         137.333328  4532.890137
2010-02-18 01:15:00         177.000000  4464.479980
2010-02-18 01:15:00         177.000000  4464.479980
2010-02-18 01:30:00         169.666672  4391.839844
2010-02-18 01:30:00         169.666672  4391.839844
2010-02-18 01:45:00         155.000000  4313.049805
2010-02-18 01:45:00         155.000000  4313.049805
2010-02-18 02:00:00         144.666672  4230.100098
2010-02-18 02:15:00         162.333328  4144.819824
2010-02-18 02:15:00         162.333328  4144.819824
2010-02-18 02:30:00         177.000000  4059.689941
2010-02-18 02:45:00         144.666672  3987.149902
2010-02-18 02:45:00         144.666672  3987.149902
2010-02-18 03:00:00         155.000000  3924.629883
2010-02-18 03:00:00         155.000000  3924.629883
2010-02-18 03:15:00         162.333328  3865.129883
2010-02-18 03:15:00         162.333328  3865.129883
2010-02-18 03:30:00         162.333328  3811.050049
2010-02-18 03:30:00         162.333328  3811.050049
2010-02-18 03:45:00         152.000000  3765.590088
2010-02-18 03:45:00         152.000000  3765.590088
2010-02-18 04:00:00         162.333328  3735.080078
2010-02-18 04:15:00         162.333328  3703.169922
2010-02-18 04:15:00         162.333328  3703.169922
2010-02-18 04:30:00         144.666672  3673.139893
2010-02-18 04:45:00         169.666672  3647.100098
2010-02-18 04:45:00         169.666672  3647.100098
2010-02-18 05:00:00         162.333328  3622.129883
2010-02-18 05:15:00         155.000000  3594.159912
2010-02-18 05:15:00         155.000000  3594.159912
2010-02-18 05:30:00         159.333328  3569.699951
2010-02-18 05:30:00         159.333328  3569.699951
2010-02-18 05:45:00         147.666672  3551.179932
2010-02-18 05:45:00         147.666672  3551.179932
2010-02-18 06:00:00         177.000000  3531.669922
2010-02-18 06:00:00         177.000000  3531.669922
2010-02-18 06:15:00         159.333328  3514.679932
2010-02-18 06:15:00         159.333328  3514.679932
2010-02-18 06:30:00         155.000000  3499.669922
2010-02-18 06:30:00         155.000000  3499.669922
2010-02-18 06:45:00         155.000000  3485.320068
2010-02-18 06:45:00         155.000000  3485.320068
2010-02-18 06:59:54.750000  162.291245    19.999992
2010-02-18 06:59:54.750000  162.291245     0.000000
2010-02-18 07:00:00         162.333328     0.000000
2010-02-18 07:00:00         162.333328     0.000000
2010-02-18 07:15:00         166.666672     0.000000
2010-02-18 07:15:00         166.666672     0.000000
2010-02-18 07:30:00         155.000000     0.000000
2010-02-18 07:30:00         155.000000     0.000000
2010-02-18 07:45:00         155.000000     0.000000
2010-02-18 07:45:00         155.000000     0.000000
                                   ...          ...

[4319 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: You could write a custom `__str__` method. Or derive a class from the original one with and overridden `__str__` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set

```
pd.options.display.large_repr = 'info'
```

The default as of v.0.13 is 'truncate'.

```
In [93]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(4319*2).reshape(4319,2))

In [94]: pd.options.display.large_repr = 'info'

In [95]: df
Out[95]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 4319 entries, 0 to 4318
Data columns (total 2 columns):
0    4319 non-null int32
1    4319 non-null int32
dtypes: int32(2)
```

---

I found this by searching for the string `'info()'` in the output of:

```
In [65]: pd.set_option?
```

---

**To make this the default behavior for interactive sessions:**

If you haven't set it already, define the environment variable [PYTHONSTARTUP](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP) to something like `/home/user/bin/startup.py`

Then edit/create `/home/user/bin/startup.py` to contain something like

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.large_repr = 'info'
```

Now, whenever you start an interactive Python session, the `startup.py` file will be executed, you'll have access to pandas through the `pd` variable, and `large_repr` default will be `'info'`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. The config_init.py file is the same, and it actually prints 60 rows, but I would like it to print the info [12] when for df if I enter 'df' instead of the rows [11]. This was the behavior before I updated to pandas 0.13.0

Comment: Oops, sorry -- I misunderstood.

Comment: Thanks, that works! Is there any way to change the default to 'info'?

Comment: To change the default value directly, line 229 in config_init.py should be changed from `cf.register_option('large_repr', 'truncate', pc_larg...`, to `cf.register_option('large_repr', 'info', pc_larg...`

Comment: Yes, with some caveats: Hacking the source code directly can become cumbersome as your list of changes grows. You'll have to re-do the changes every time you upgrade pandas. Also, if you rely upon non-standard behavior, your ability to use other people's code or vice versa may be hampered.