# Dataframe print info

Tags: python, pandas

Before when I printed a dataframe, information (df.info) about it screening. Now the values are printed.

Has someone any idea how to change this parameter ?

```
>>> df
               0
DATES               
2014-01-01 -0.259806
2014-01-02 -1.221857
...

[10 rows x 1 columns]

>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 10 entries, 2014-01-01 00:00:00 to 2014-01-10 00:00:00
Freq: D
Data columns (total 1 columns):
0    10 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1)
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand the question.

Comment: I want make df and have df.info as the result. With the old version of Pandas I have that !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set

```
pd.options.display.large_repr = 'info'
```

or modify python [startup](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP)

For more details refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21482546/change-pandas-0-13-0-print-dataframe-to-print-dataframe-like-in-earlier-versio).