# reading tab-delimited data without header in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm having trouble using `pandas` to open tab-delimited data without headers.

My test data (actually contains 200 lines, of which I am showing the first 10):

```
Tag19184    CTAAC   hffef   1   a   36  -   chr1    10006   0   36M 36
Tag19184    CTAAC   hffef   1   a   36  -   chr1    10012   0   36M 36
Tag19184    CTAAC   hffef   1   a   36  -   chr1    10018   0   36M 36
Tag19184    CTAAC   hffef   1   a   36  -   chr1    10024   0   36M 36
Tag19184    CTAAC   hffef   1   a   36  -   chr1    10030   0   36M 36
Tag19184    CTAAC   hffef   1   a   36  -   chr1    10036   0   36M 36
Tag19184    CTAAC   hffef   1   a   36  -   chr1    10042   0   36M 36
Tag20198    CTAAC   hffef   1   a   36  -   chr1    10048   0   36M 36
Tag20198    CTAAC   hffef   1   a   36  -   chr1    10054   0   36M 36
Tag45093    CTAAC   hffef   1   a   36  -   chr1    10060   0   36M 36
```

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('in_test.txt',sep='\t',header=None)
print df
```

However, I get the following output, which I don't think I can use to further process data (?):

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 200 entries, 0 to 199
Data columns:
X.1     200  non-null values
X.2     200  non-null values
X.3     200  non-null values
X.4     200  non-null values
X.5     200  non-null values
X.6     200  non-null values
X.7     200  non-null values
X.8     200  non-null values
X.9     200  non-null values
X.10    200  non-null values
X.11    200  non-null values
X.12    200  non-null values
dtypes: int64(5), object(7)
```

The [tutorial here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html) suggests that `print df` should just give me the corresponding data frame. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are getting the it read correctly, but:

1. See: [change pandas 0.13.0 "print dataframe" to print dataframe like in earlier versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21482546/change-pandas-0-13-0-print-dataframe-to-print-dataframe-like-in-earlier-version), this is what pandas do in the older versions. So, update will solve it.
2. You can use `ipython notebook`, where `DataFrames` will show up as HTML tables.
3. You can use `df.head(5)` (similar to `r`'s `head`) to get the first a few rows just to make sure your `DataFrame` is correct.

Comment: Thanks again. I'm getting the same kind of summary, this time with values of `5` instead of `200` ^-^);;; let me try some more

Comment: You must be using an early version, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21482546/change-pandas-0-13-0-print-dataframe-to-print-dataframe-like-in-earlier-version

Comment: I tried both stackoverflow links but it invariably gives me an error of the type `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'options'` or `has no attribute set_option`. I installed `python-pandas` using `apt-get install` which I just figured, only installs a very very old version: `pandas.__version__ = 0.7.0`. I'll get back to your post after I figure out how to update it. :)

Comment: :P, that is ancient! We are on `0.14.0` now. If you have issues with dependency and stuff, give `ananconda python` distribution a try.

Comment: Hmm.. is it even possible to use `ipython` or `anaconda python` on a non-GUI, command-line based Ubuntu machine? I am having trouble installing the correct version of `openpyxl`

Comment: You won't be able to use `ipython notebook` or `ipython qtconsole` or anything that require graphic interface, but the other features of `anaconda python` should be functional.

Comment: Thanks!! I figured out the `openpyxl` dependency problem and now it's working fine :) The output of `print df.head(5)` now prints a table but the table is cut two times with a \ is that just to make it easier to visualize longer rows on a small screen?

Comment: Yep, you can change the default behavior with `pd.set_option()`.